# vim Search Replace should use replaced text in following searches

Tags: vim

I have a data file (comma separated) that has a lot of `NA`s (It was generated by R). I opened the file in vim and tried to replace all the `NA` values to empty strings.

Here is a sample slimmed down version of a record in the file:

```
1,1,NA,NA,NA,NATIONAL,NA,1,NANA,1,AMERICANA,1
```

Once I am done with the search-replace, the intended output should be:

```
1,1,,,,NATIONAL,,1,NANA,1,AMERICANA,1
```

In other words, all the `NA`s should be replaced except the words `NATIONAL`, `NANA` and `AMERICANA`.

I used the following command in vim to do this:

```
1, $ s/\,NA\,/\,\,/g
```

But, it doesn't seem to work. Here is the output that I get:

```
1,1,,NA,,NATIONAL,,1,NANA,1,AMERICANA,1
```

As you can see, there is one `,NA,` that is left out of the replacement process.

Does anyone have a good way to fix it? Thanks.

A trivial solution is to run the same command again and it will take care of the remaining `,NA,`. However, it is not a feasible solution because my actual data file has 100s of columns and 500K+ rows each with a variable number of `NA`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `%` instead of `1,$` (`%` means "the buffer" aka the whole file).
2. You don't need `\,`. `,` works fine.
3. Vim finds discrete, non-overlapping matches. so in `,NA,NA,NA,` it only finds the first `,NA,` and third `,NA,` as the middle one doesn't have its own separate surrounding `,`. We can modify the match to not include certain characters of our regex with `\zs` (start) and `\ze` (end). These modify our regex to find matches that are surrounded by other characters, but our matches don't actually include them, so we can match all the `NA` in `,NA,NA,NA,`.

TL;DR: `%s/,\zsNA\ze,//g`

Answer (score 2):

1. `,` doesn't have a special meaning so you don't have to escape it:

   ```
   :1,$s/,NA,/,,/g
   ```

   Which doesn't solve your problem.
2. You can use `%` as a shorthand for `1,$`:

   ```
   :%s/,NA,/,,/g
   ```

   Which doesn't solve your problem either.
3. The best way to match all those `NA` words to the exclusion of other words containing `NA` would be to use word boundaries:

   ```
   :%s/,\<NA\>,/,,/g
   ```

   Which still doesn't solve your problem.
4. Which makes those commas, that you used to restrict the match to `NA` and that are causing the error, useless:

   ```
   :%s/\<NA\>//g
   ```

See `:help :range` and `:help \<`.

Comment: Points 1-3 are only intermediary steps. The solution is point 4.